# Why Java StringReader throws IOException?

Tags: java, api, stringreader

Today I was working with Java class `StringReader` and I found it very annoying that it throws IOException on `read` method. I know that it extends `Reader` class in which method `read` throw IOException but I think that it is not needed for StringReader. This class doesn't use any external resources that might cause errors.

After short investigation I found out that `StringReader#read` throws `IOException` if string which this class reads is null but de facto this **can't happen** because if we would try to pass null to `StringReader` constructor it throws NPE.

What do you think about it, is it good practice to always throw the same exceptions as super class?

---

Edit:
As noted by U Mad Reader is a class not interface.

Comment: The throws declaration in `StringReader` is mandatory, because the interface `Reader` requires it even if the implementing class won't never throws such an exception.

Comment: What are the reasons for down votes ?

Comment: Reader is a class, not an interface and you can override a function with an implementation with fewer or no exceptions declared. And it will work. So there's no reason for StringReader to have them declared.

Comment: @UMad, that is true but the Reader is abstract and the method read came from Readable interface.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The makers of StringReader could declare read without IOException. That was a mistake on their part.

Comment: @UMad, Mark Reinhold the developer of StringReader class has done it perfectly. The mistake is on your side as you think that IOExcpetion is StringReader is not valid.

Comment: If he declared `read` (and other methods) without the exception then the following would hold true: `Reader r = new StringReader; r.read();` would require exception handling. `StringReader r = new StringReader;r.read();` would not require exception handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at [StringReader#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29).

Look at the source code of [StringReader#read()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/StringReader.java#StringReader.read%28%29) method. It calls `ensureOpen()` method that is actually throwing `IOException` because `ensureOpen()` checks to make sure that the stream has not been closed.

**If reader is closed and then after `read()` is called again then what will happen?**

Source Code directly from above link (Look at the comments):

```
/**
 * Reads a single character.
 *
 * @return     The character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been
 *             reached
 *
 * @exception  IOException  If an I/O error occurs
 */
public int read() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen();
        if (next >= length)
            return -1;
        return str.charAt(next++);
    }
}

/** Check to make sure that the stream has not been closed */
private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
    if (str == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
}

/**
 * Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with
 * it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(),
 * ready(), mark(), or reset() invocations will throw an IOException.
 * Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.
 */
public void close() {
    str = null;
}
```

Comment: I did it before asking a question :). I found out that ensureOpen checks if input string is not null, which CAN'T HAPPEN.

Comment: But for safer side a expert Java programmer has put this check.

Comment: If reader is `closed` then after `read` is called again then what will happen?

Comment: It can happen. I checked the constructor and found a `NullPointerException` would be thrown before. But then I searched the whole code and found the close() method, modifying the str member variabel. Reading the JavaDoc lead to the conclusion, that read() must throw the IOException.

Comment: @Harmlezz That's what I have already asked in my last comment.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is not a good practice to throw the same exceptions as the super class or interface definition if your implementation ensures it will never happen. I would always reduce a signature to the bare minimum required.

The `IOException` is required for all the implementations imaginable, including file sources and streams and sockets etc. Without, such implementations could not notify their errors as a checked exception. But if an implementation has no need to throw a checked exception (which is often annoying for the calling code) removing it from the implementing class does no harm, but removes some burden.

**UPDATE:**

I have found the reason why the method read() **must** throw an `IOException`: because of the contract defined for the close() method. From the JavaDoc:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), or reset() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

Comment: haah, the worderful world of checked exception :-)

Comment: You can't do it here.

Comment: @Braj: I do not know what's wrong? `ensureOpen()` does not explain why the `IOException` must be thrown. Only if you follow the code further to the `close()` method you find the real cause. And besides: it is a platform for answering questions and not for winning a price. So keep cool :-)

Comment: Its actually `ensureOpen()` method that throws it. Then I investigated how `this.str` can be assigned to `null` then I come to `close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement a method of interface in your class it is not required to provide same exception arguments. Same case apply when you override declaration of method from super class.

```
public class MyReader implements Readable {

    @Override
    public int read(CharBuffer cb)  {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

But then you are not using the interface in proper way. And you do not benefit from this in case when you are coding to interface.

```
Readable readable = new MyReader();

        try {
            readable.read(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Even in the `MyReader` do not expose the `IOException` you still have to use try block. So in case you do not throw exception of the method you implement may point that you missed something in your implementation of that method. So IMHO it is not a good practice do to so.

The reason why `StringBuilder` throws `IOException` is not that it implement the interface `Readable`. The reason of that is validation of the input in method `ensureOpen()` that throw an `IOException` when input is null. Then input can be null when method `close()` is called or you pass null to constructor. As method close is abstract it must have some effect in the child class. The expected is that after you call close you can no longer read from it and you will get IOException.

This is perfect, clean and solid implementation that take into account all potential use cases.